# How to execute Cypress code for a particular view such as mobile /Tablet?

Tags: cypress

I am current creating using cypress for automation. The main motive is to execute the code on different devices.

My code is below:

```
describe('Page objects', function() {
  before(function() {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:8100/tab1")
  })

  it('shows authenticated user', function() {
    if (Cypress.env('isMobile')) {
      cy.log("mobile view is executed")
    } else if(Cypress.env('isTablet')) {
      cy.log("Tablet view is executed")
    } else {
      cy.log("Desktop view is executed")
    }
  })           
})
```

I wanted to execute the above code through the terminal. I've tried referencing this blog post:
https://maximilianschmitt.me/posts/cypress-testing-mobile-tablet-desktop/

But I'm getting an error while executing it using `node integration-tests.js --mobile`.

How should I execute a particular spec file with a mobile / tablet view?

Comment: Hey would be nice if you can share a minimal runnable example. And of course the error message you receive

Comment: Have you concidered using `cy.viewport(x, y)`? You need to configure the x and y yourself, but you can force to use the specific dimensions of a device.

Comment: i am not using cy.viewport.i have added a js file which consists of the screensize.I want to use that file and execute test case

Comment: I am currently using that for desktop and for mobile testing.

Comment: I have added a detailed answer, please upvote if useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring to the post of `maximilianschmitt.me`, I have successfully implemented that in my project. First I have created two different folders for cypress test, one for `web` and another for `mobile`. Then copy the 'integration-tests.js` into the root folder.
note: *In my case we are using Circle.ci in CI/CD and update the package.json file for two separate test runs.*

Also I have made some additions in my integration-test.js file. The reason for that was, 
while running the `integration-tests.js` file cypress was not able to identify the '--spec' option passed in script path, through which I can specify to run specs only from certain folders, refer here.. ([flag supports globs](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1845)). So I have added a new `const spec = argv.includes('--spec');` inside the integration-tests.js. My mobile tests were slightly different from web based on responsiveness. Cypress was running all of the web, mobile tests from both folders without the `--spec` flag/supports globs pattern and it was failing the tests.

Second change was to add a new variable under cypressOptions.

```
const cypressOptions = {
    // Expose the device type as Cypress environment variables
    env: {
        ...... // add isSpec along with other cypressOptions
        isSpec: argv.includes('--spec'),

    },
```

Now under the config section add the path for mobile

```
config: {
 integrationFolder: "cypress/integration/mobile",
}
```

Finally under the function runCypress you need to pass the `--spec` along with mobile

```
  function runCypress(){ 

    if (argv.includes('--mobile' && '--spec')) {   
            return cypress.run(cypressOptions)
    }...
```

Now you need to separate both runs in `package.json` file as below:

```
"scripts": {
    "cy:web-test": "set CYPRESS_RETRIES=2 && cypress run --record --key <here> --spec cypress/integration/desktop/**/*",
    "cy:mobile-test":"node integration-tests.js --mobile --spec cypress/integration/mobile/**/*"
  }
```

note>> *I have added a plug-in for `cypress retries`, you can remove the same from the script path under web related run.*